# I'm using JMeter to record a test case but HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is converting a simple HTTP POST to https

Tags: jmeter

I'm using JMeter to record a test case but HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is converting a simple HTTP POST to https and also the server name is invalid. I'm calling a JSON webservice and the path to webservice is coming in the server name. Similarly Port is also missin

Please note that I'm using Jmeter version 2.13 and testing a MS word plugin

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder) does not record activity by MS Word Plugin, so I suppose it is recording some other traffic from your browser which explains why you have wrong:

- Server name
- Https instead of http

You should show what is recorded and give more details on MS Word Plugin.

Comment: I guess you missed the main part of the question. Word Plugin is making the JSOn calls and the server name actually contains the path to JSON web service.

Comment: unless you give more details on test plan, show logs , it is impossible to help you